# What value should be passed with AsyncStorage?

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

I am currently a beginner of react native and I want to know if I wanted to login and store user data using AsyncStorage, what key and value should be passed? 
`AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

```
     UserLogin = () =>{

    const { username }  = this.state ;


    fetch('https://www.example.com/React/user-login.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({

       username: username,

     })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {

           // If server response message same as Data Matched
          if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
           {
             login(username, password).then(authenticationToken => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('token', authenticationToken)
})

               //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
               this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen', { username:username });

           }
           else{

             Alert.alert(responseJson);
           }

         }).catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });

     }
```

If I were to say if logged in, then `AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`, then that could work if I want to store say the user's username so that I can display it on their profile page?

Comment: What’s the php example code for? That does not have any relevance on the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just guess I just figured you would know where to place `AsyncStorage`... I read it can be placed out side the `responseJson`

Comment: The code here is php code that would run on the backend. React native uses JavaScript running on the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage parameters are both strings, so you can store serialised json data or just a plain string.

```
// Some code that logs someone in and gets an authentication token which then is stored
login(username, password).then(authenticationToken => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('token', authenticationToken)
})

// then somewhere else in your code
AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(authenticationToken => {
  console.log(‘the token’, authenticationToken)
})
```

Comment: thank you. Also, what would I need to put for `authenticatonToken`? Just make up one?

Comment: That’s just some example code showing how you may use AsyncStorage to store and retrieve some string value. It’s up to you to implement something to fetch the data you want to store.

Comment: I updated my code above, would it be something like this? If not, I can look at the authenication videos until I figure it out.

Comment: If I have a question about authentication, it should be a separate question. Your question was about how to store a value to AsyncStorage, which I believe has been answered.